# How do I create a responsive, scaling "pile" effect on divs in CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I create a "pile" effect like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arH3Y.png)?

I'd like the formation/spacing of the pile to stay as it is, and for the pile to shift left or right as the window is resized.

I've been fiddling around with absolute/relative positioning, but I'm a CSS newbie and I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

This is what I have so far:

```css
.boxes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 10vw;
  width:fit-content;
  padding: 0px 10px 4px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0);
}
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  width:fit-content;
  left: 16vw;
  bottom: 13vh;
  padding: 0px 10px 4px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0);
  transform: rotate(10.84deg);
}
.box3 {
  position: relative;
  width:fit-content;
  left: 25vw;
  bottom: 20vh;
  padding: 0px 10px 4px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0);
  transform: rotate(21deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box1">box1</div>
  <div class="box2">box2</div>
  <div class="box3">box3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set boxes to relative and it's child absolute like:

```css
.boxes {
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.box1  {
  position: absolute;
  ...
}
.box2{
position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    left: 19vw;
    bottom: 7vh;    
    width: 70px;
    transform: rotate(16deg);
    padding: 0px 10px 4px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgb(0 0 0);
}
.box3 {
    left: 27vw;
    width: 40px;
    bottom: 32vh;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 10px 4px 10px;
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgb(0 0 0);
}
//etc..
```

Try to play with rotate [transform - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `#wrapper` with a `width` and a `height`. Then I gave the wrapper `position: relative;` because we will position the single elements with `position: absolute;`.

Here is the code I used:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 70px;
}

#purple {
  width: 100px;
height: 30px;
background: purple;
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
left: 145px;
transform: rotate(25deg);
}

#green {
  width: 50px;
height: 30px;
background: green;
position: absolute;
bottom: 63px;
left: 177px;
transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

#red {
  width: 100px;
height: 30px;
background: red;
position: absolute;
bottom: 21px;
left: 220px;
transform: rotate(28deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="purple"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="red"></div>
</div>
```